# Maven Build - SoX / Audio Conversion

Tags: maven, audio, build, sox

I am getting into Maven as a build tool and am trying to convert a whole lot of manual processes to something streamlined.

I have a web application that uses audio files that currently at deployment time, are run through a SoX tasK: http://sox.sourceforge.net/ to convert them to a desired sample rate and destination folder. (manual step using a .bat file)

Is there a plugin or simplified way of integrating the audio build component into the Maven build?

I have thought about using an Ant script embedded in, but not sure if this is the right direction to be heading.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult to create your own Maven plugin (Mojo).  Take a look at the [Mojo Developers Cookbook](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mojo+Developer+Cookbook)

[*Edit* ]
I should also mention that you could run the `.bat` script using the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) as a less portable alternative. The [`exec` plugin source code](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/source-repository.html) is also a good place to start were you to write your own SoX plugin.

Comment: Ah I didn't think of writing a plugin, thank you for the link, I will look into it more